# For loop within GeoGraphics

Tags: list-manipulation, geographics

I'm trying to plot a map with a list of destinations as Disks.

I first input the cities into a list such as:

```
destinations = {GeoPosition[New York City],
GeoPosition[Mumbai],
...}
```

where "New York City" is input using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> method to access interpreter and specify it as a city.

Then I have something summarizing to:

```
GeoGraphics[{
Black,
Disk[For[i=1, i<Length[destinations]+1,i++,destinations[[i]],1],
...
Disk[city,1],
},
...
]
```

This outputs a map with my desired projection settings such as background, range, and the single disk that I specified separately like:

```
Disk[city,1],
```

I have also tried to put the `Disk` function inside a for loop like:

```
For[i=1, i<Length[destinations]+1,i++,Disk[destinations[[i]],1]],
```

It's not an incorrect indexing of the destinations list either, because

```
For[i=1, i<Length[destinations]+1,i++,Print[destinations[[i]]]]
```

outputs the correct amount of cities, whereas

```
For[i=0, i<Length[destinations],i++,Print[destinations[[i]]]]
```

outputs a first item of "List" and doesn't print the last city.

Is it possible to use for loops within a `GeoGraphics` function, or would I be required to add a `Disk` function line for each item I would like to plot instead of iterating through a list?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `For` loops.

Instead you can [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) `Disk` on `destinations`; that is, use `Disk /@ destinations` (`Disk[#, 5]& /@ destinations` if you want a radius of `5` instead of the default radius `1`).

```
cities = {Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}], 
    Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
    Entity["City", {"Bombay", "Maharashtra", "India"}], 
    Entity["City", {"Delhi", "Delhi", "India"}]};
destinations = GeoPosition /@ cities;

GeoGraphics[{Black, Disk /@ destinations}]
```

[image]

**Notes:** If you have to use a `For` loop you can do:

```
disks = {}; 
For[i = 1, i <= Length[destinations], i++, AppendTo[disks, Disk[destinations[[i]]]]];
GeoGraphics[{Black, disks}]
```

> same picture

Alternatively, you can use `Table`:

```
Table[Disk[i], {i, destinations}] == disks
```

> True

and if you have to use a `For` loop inside `GeoGraphics`

```
GeoGraphics[{Black, disks = {}; 
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[destinations], i++, 
   AppendTo[disks, Disk[destinations[[i]]]]]; disks}]
```

> same picture

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly thank you!